# difference between auto and decltype in c++0x

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

I'm having trouble with auto and decltype.

```
void f(const vector<int>& a, vector<float>& b)
{
    typedef decltype(a[0]*b[0]) Tmp;
    for (int i=0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
      auto p0 = new auto(a[i]*b[i]);
      auto p1 = new decltype(a[i]*b[i]);
      *p0=a[i]*b[i];
      *p1=a[i]*b[i];
      cout<<*p0<<endl;
      cout<<*p1<<endl;
      delete p0;
      delete p1;
   }
}

 int main()
{

    vector<float>vec2;
    vec2.push_back(2.0);

    vector<int>vec1;
    vec1.push_back(5);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs well in GCC4.7. Could I use 'new auto(a[0]*b[0])' to allocate memory for the type of a[0]*b[0]? And I can not distinguish the difference between decltype and auto in this case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is that this:

```
  new auto(a[i]*b[i]);
```

is allocating an object of whatever type `a[i]*b[i]` is, and *initializes the object with that value*. That is, the parentheses are an initializer. Whereas using decltype:

```
  new decltype(a[i]*b[i]);
```

allocates an object of the same type, *but there is no initializer*. The object is default initialized.

Basically `decltype(...)` is treated as a type, while `auto` specifies a type to be deduced from an intializer.

---

#### C++11 Style

Since `new` shouldn't be used except in special cases, if for some reason these semantics are needed they'd properly be written something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args> T make_unique(Args &&...args) {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

template<typename T> T make_unique_auto(T &&t) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>{std::forward<T>(t)};
}

// new auto(a[i]*b[i])
auto p1 = make_unique_auto(a[i]*b[i]);

// new decltype(a[i]*b[i])
auto p2 = make_unique<decltype(a[i]*b[i])>();
```

Furthermore, if one gets used to using C++11 uniform initialization universally the and if one stops using parentheses for initialization then eventually the parentheses used with `decltype` cease to look to the programmer like an initializer.

For this reason and others, I think it would be good for a 'modern' C++11 style to include a rule that one should always use braces and never use parentheses for initialization. (And constructors that cannot be called except with parentheses, e.g. `std::vector<int>(int,int);`, should be avoided; don't create new ones and don't use legacy ones.)

Comment: In other words, the first is the same as `new decltype(a[i]*b[i])(a[i]*b[i]);`.

Comment: I am suddenly crying a little inside. I wish *never* to see that.

Comment: Wouldn't `new auto {a[i]*b[i]};` allocate a `std::initializer_list`? the type of `c`in `auto c = {a[i]*b[i]};` is `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @Kleist Aww, I'd forgotten about that. Not the first time that rule has seemed unfortunate to me. Although in this case it's both better and worse; using uniform initialization with `auto` and `new` is explicitly forbidden, but fortunately C++11 (well C++14) style doesn't permit the use of `new` at all. If for some reason the exact semantics called for here were needed it would properly be done like `make_unique_auto(a[i]*b[i])` and `make_unique<decltype(a[i]*b[i])>()`.